# If F is a simple module, is $F^n $ semi simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If F is a simple module, is $F^n $ semi simple?

I'm assuming this is true by the classification theorem

Comment: What classification theorem? This is true by definition.

Comment: Simple module for what algebra? If $F$ is a field, it can be made into a simple $F[x]$-module in at least two different ways, but the vector space $F^n$ may or may not be a simple $F[x]$-module.

Comment: @Tobias: it depends on your definition; there are several equivalent ones but the equivalences aren't trivial, and this is easy to see for some but not others. For example your definition might be that every submodule is a direct summand.